# Why is the EXIF time different from the time the image was captured?

Tags: metadata, gps, date

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S that I use to capture geotagged photos.  The Android application GPS Essentials is used to collect the images and GPS Essentials names the images with the Date and time (160728-131554.jpg).
For this example the capture date and time are correctly written as the image name.

I am using Python and the Python Image Library to read and print the various EXIF information and noticed that the EXIF time is recorded as 16:11:12 while the file name and the correct capture time is 13:15:54.

**Why is the EXIF time not the same as the local time?**

This image was captured during Pacific Daylight Savings Time.   I would understand if the EXIF was recording Greenwich time but that would be a 7 hour difference and not a 3hr and 56 min difference.

Please help me understand the difference between the two times.

Comment: Oh, I see that the later time is the time that the image was copied to a Windows 7 computer.  Windows is altering the EXIF information?

Comment: _Which_ exif time are you looking at?

Comment: The GPS timestamp in the EXIF is usually based on the time of the last GPS fix, rather than the capture time of the photo. Please see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77973/when-exactly-is-gpstimestamp

Answer (score 2):

EXIF tag DateTime is the data and time that the image was last modified and will be rewritten if the image is moved from one directory to another.

EXIF Tag DateTimeOriginal is the capture data and time.

My application GPS Essentials only writes out to DateTime and not DateTimeOriginal and this was the source of my confusion.